# ionViewWillEnter doesn't work on entering the page

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

As the title suggests, my function doesn't trigger once I access the page itself. I have a button that is supposed to redirect me to another page, yet the page itself doesn't load nor the function. The code at the moment looks like this:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController, AlertController} from "ionic-angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-patch-notes',
  templateUrl: 'patch-notes.html'
})

export class PatchNotes {

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Patch Notes',
      message: "Introduceti adresa de email pentru a va trimite un link de resetare parola.",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Anulati',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Ok clicked');
          }
        },
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an ionic `page` and not a simple angular `component`? Usually ionic pages follow the name pattern `.page.ts` and `.page.html`

Comment: try it in IonViewDidEnter?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the alert controller is created and displayed before the page is even loaded. [Ionic lifecycles states](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle) that his hook fires

> between the "Begin Page Transition" and "Page Fully Transitioned" stages.

I have had a lot of success tying this kind of logic to [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). You will need to update your class def to `export class PatchNotes implements OnInit`. The fact that this wasn't done suggests that fransicso neto's suggestion may be accurate as well. If you aren't already, it's always a good idea to generate pages using the [Ionic CLI](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli).